# Issue selecting only one item with multiple ListBoxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET and I've tried to create a simple application. My need is to create a form with some listboxes and I want to have only one item selected at the same time. I've written this code in the `Form1 Class`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub aggiornaQKI(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles ListBox1.Click, ListBox9.Click, ListBox8.Click, ListBox7.Click, _
                ListBox6.Click, ListBox5.Click, ListBox4.Click, ListBox3.Click, ListBox2.Click

        If sender.selectedindex >= 0 Then

            If sender.name <> "ListBox1" Then ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox2" Then ListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox3" Then ListBox3.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox4" Then ListBox4.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox5" Then ListBox5.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox6" Then ListBox6.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox7" Then ListBox7.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox8" Then ListBox8.SelectedIndex = -1
            If sender.name <> "ListBox9" Then ListBox9.SelectedIndex = -1

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

How it's possible that I have more than one item selected at runtime? The only thing that I do is to click between listboxes items very quickly!

I have no reputation to post an image but I can guarantee that is like I've said. I've tried to run the application on another pc but is the same.

I have `Windows 7 64 bit` and `.NET 4.0`.

In a new version, I've written a `Console.WriteLine(sender.name)` before the first if. When the issue occur, it seems that the last click event was lost because I don't find the name of the last listbox clicked!

To confirm this, when the two items are selected, if I insert a breakpoint and go to see the value of the selecteditem property of the listboxes, I see effectively that two of that have values <> -1.

Comment: Are you complaining about the fact that at the moment the mouse is down, you have two selections on the screen?

Comment: Hy Abbas, not when the mouse is down but after a click, so i have no hands on my mouse and two selected items on screen ...

Comment: I'm not Abbas.  Your code works (except your failure to cast sender into a ListBox object), so it's unclear what issue you have.  SelectedIndexChanged is the more appropriate event to use.

Comment: Sorry for my error LarsTech. I'm not able to understand how is possible that i can

Comment: Try duplicating the problem on a new project, with just two or three ListBoxes.  My guess is you have code somewhere else affecting this.

Comment: I've tryed also in C#. The same.

Comment: You keep complaining that it doesn't work, but you aren't improving your question to duplicate the problem for your audience.

Answer (score 1):

The event you may want to use is SelectedIndexChanged.  So instead of

```
handles Listbox1.Click
```

try

```
handles Listbox1.SelectedIndexChanged, Listbox2.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Comment: Yes i've already tried yesterday and with that event the problem not occur: but why?

Comment: because the click event is generic, on every control, for anytime you click within the real estate of the control, and I believe before the index is actually changed.

Comment: Tanks for your reply. Maybe is as you have explained ... I was only looking for something behind that i can avoid in the future ... I'm not sure i will be always able to identify the "more appropriate"